# How to convert the month name in english text in datetime to arabic text using C#?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have a date which is displayed on 12 July 2013. I am using the format "dd MMMM yyyy". I want to display the month text i.e. July in Arabic text. Is there anyway?

Am getting يوليه as result instead يوليو, My client, saying: the month of July is “يوليو” in Arabic, while on the website it is showing as “يوليه”. Which is wrong,
can anyone help me on this?

Please find the code below.

What I have tried:

```
CultureInfo uiCulture1 = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture; //'ar-AE'
DateTime dDateTime2 = DateTime.Parse(dt.ToString(), uiCulture1, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
lblDate.Value = dt.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");
```

Comment: I really don't know the solution for this but the meaning of  يوليه  is "In JULY" .

Comment: Yes ...., When you try it on our local machine its showing يوليو which is correct. But when we hosting our application then it's getting wrong  يوليه. what may be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
var month = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM", new CultureInfo("ar-AE"));
Console.WriteLine(month);
```

result `أكتوبر`

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the

```
dt.ToString()
```

in the Date.Parse. The dDateTime2  is getting set to 07 December instead of 12 July because I think the Culture in question is defaulting to dd-mm-yyyy for date format.

```
var dt = new DateTime(2013, 07, 12);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")); //12 July 2013

CultureInfo uiCulture1 = new CultureInfo("ar-AE"); //'ar-AE'
DateTime dDateTime2 = DateTime.Parse(dt.ToString(), uiCulture1, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);

Console.WriteLine(dDateTime2.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")); // 07 December 2013

Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy", uiCulture1)); //12 يوليو 2013
```

Comment: Thank you... I have tried these in local machine its showing correct but if you hosted the website its showing wrong

Comment: @Reshmy where do you host?

Comment: In Production server

Answer (score 0):

provide the culture info in dateTime.toString()

```
        var dateTime = DateTime.Now;

        var uiCulture = new CultureInfo("ar-AE");
        Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString("dd MMM yyyy",uiCulture));
```

Comment: I have tried these in local machine its showing correct but if you hosted the website its showing wrong